# How Do I Change the Exported Flat File Column Delimiter VS2012 SSIS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I've successfully created an SSIS package that exports data from our database into a flat file. The last thing I need to do is to change the exported file delimiter.  However, I cannot find where I can choose the delimiter.  I'm assuming that it is a default somewhere in the set up of the Flat File Destination, but now that I need to change the export file delimiter, I cannot find where the export file delimiter is specified or configured.

Could someone please point out where, or if, I can change the delimiter in the Exported flat file from the default comma to another character, preferably pipe "|".

I'm using VS2012 Ultimate V11.06... Update 4, SSIS V11.03...

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Flat File Connection Manager navigate to the Columns tab. Modify the Column Delimiter property as needed.

See example below:

[image]