# SSIS: Two different error with different driver. One is 32bit and another is 64 bit. Running in 32 bit cause another driver to fail

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working on a SSIS package which connects to the server and dump data into Excel file and then send that excel file through email to the client.
I am using ADO.net(Provider: .Net Providers\Odbc Data Provider) driver to connect with Server and which is 64 bit and excel destination to connect the file on my local.
When i start to run the package in my SSDT with property `Run64BitRUNtime = true`, i am getting following error.

```
 Source: CFEReport Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"     Description: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2016-06-17 13:27:56.81     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: CFE Report Generation Excel Destination [32]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2016-06-17 13:27:56.82     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: CFE Report Generation SSIS.Pipeline     Description: Excel Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2016-06-17 13:27:56.82     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: CFE Report Generation SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2016-06-17 13:27:56.82     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: CFE Report Generation      Description: There were errors during task validation.
```

So i searched over internet and find that i should set that property `Run64BitRUNtime = false` and run it in 32 bit. I try that and i am able to run it successfully.
But when i tried to run it in SQL server 2012 as creating job and run it daily, i am getting following error. (I also set the property in SQL Job to run it in 32 bit environment by checking `Use 32 Bit runtime` option in Execution option)

```
 Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.6020.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  1:19:17 PM  Error: 2016-06-17 13:19:17.98     Code: 0xC0208449     Source: CFE Report Generation RAR TableQuery [93]     Description: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {F2DAE648-B39C-4F43-8EBE-BBA6E11EC7AA} with the following error message: "ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".  End Error  Error: 2016-06-17 13:19:17.98     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: CFE Report Generation SSIS.Pipeline     Description: RAR TableQuery failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.  End Error  Error: 2016-06-17 13:19:17.98     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: CFE Report Generation SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2016-06-17 13:19:17.98     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: CFE Report Generation      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  1:19:17 PM  Finished: 1:19:17 PM  Elapsed:  0.78 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

Can you help to solve this problem? Thanks in advance
I want to run this package in 64 bit what should i do to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One driver exists in the 32 bit space, one in 64 and the twain shall never meet. Your choices are to either find a driver in the opposite space or break your package up into two separate packages so that you can run one using the 32bit dtexec and one as the 64 bit dtexec. The RAW file destination/source can be of help in this situation.

Comment: Thanks. I installed 64 bit of MS Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable on Server. I reopen my SSIS package in SSDT and try it again with excel. if i run it in 32bit (Run64BitRUNtime = false) then it is working otherwise it is giving me the same error. Now I divide package into two part(one in RAW file and another RAW file to Excel) and it's working by running one package in 32 bit and another in 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem recently when we deployed my SSIS Packages onto DEV SQL Servers which were `64-bit`.

The solution is to install the `64-bit` version of the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255) on the `64-bit` **SQL Server** Server

Make sure you select the one that has the `_64` in the `exe` name as show below.

[image]

This redistributable is the one that has the `64-bit` version of the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver used by all office files including MS Access, MS Excel and MS Word. So don't worry about it's name.

Comment: I installed 64 bit of MS Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable on Server. I reopen my SSIS package in SSDT and try it again with excel. if i run it in 32bit (Run64BitRUNtime = false) then it is working otherwise it is giving me the same error.

Comment: Now I divide package into two part(one in RAW file and another RAW file to Excel) and it's working by running one package in 32 bit and another in 64bit but still i want to know what is wrong i am doing with your solution(i.e Installing 64 bit version)

Comment: When you run the package in SSDT, it's on your local machine, right? That has the 32-bit driver and that will be the one used when you set `Run64BitRUNtime = false` while in debug mode on your local machine. When you execute the same deployed package on the SQL Server which is 64-bit, you need the 64-bit driver. Makes sense? I am not clear on your 2nd comment.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to save the files as CSV and then open it with  Excel. That would allow your preference of using 64 Bit. Another approach would be to try using the 64 Bit ODBC drivers.

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255)

(It states it is the Access DB Engine but if you look at the 'Additional Information' it lists Excel as part of this package as well)

I would be curious to know how this works out for you.

Comment: I can not use CSV because my data has lots of comma(,). if i use CSV then some data falls into other column. I installed 64 bit of MS Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable on Server. I reopen my SSIS package in SSDT and try it again with excel. if i run it in 32bit (Run64BitRUNtime = false) then it is working otherwise it is giving me the same error.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I had commas in my table data and was able to resolve it by using a '|' pipe character for the column deliminator. In SSIS you can specify what character you want to separate your columns with, just find a character that is not in your data. [Changing Column Deliminators] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356180/how-do-i-change-the-exported-flat-file-column-delimiter-vs2012-ssis)

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers are basically right on, The articles that point you to use the 32 bit execution don't help if you are actually running the 64 bit driver of its not installed at all.  As @Shiva points you to the right driver for most of your Excel work you will need.  If you want to run 32 bit select the AccessDatabaseEngine that is 32.  If you want 64 get the 64 version.  To further complicate this though if you want to save as older file format than Office 2010 then you actually need the Access 2007 driver as well and it has to be installed prior to installing the 2010 version.  Then if you want to use 2013 and newer versions of excel then you actually need the newer AccessDatabaseEngine drivers as well.

So what I do because I get Excel files from lots of different sources is I get all of the Access Database Engine Drivers and install them all in order of oldest to newest that was I can select the most appropriate for the job I am working with.  In your case because you are creating the Excel file you have some more flexibility in regards to just choosing the driver you want.

Just one last piece of this.  You will need the driver(s) on your development system and the server that will actually run the SSIS job.