# How to export a Flat File by using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I want to export a flat file .csv extension from SSIS.

My data is like this:

```
Customer Customer Name    Address
AA00     Hla Hla,Ms       Yangon
AA02     Kyaw,U           Taunggyi
```

I want the flat file to have the below format:

```
Customer Customer Name    Address
AA00     Hla Hla,Ms       Yangon
AA02     Kyaw,U           Taunggyi
```

I added OLEDB Source & Flat File Destination in Data Flow. My SQL statement is from OLEDB Source

```
SELECT CustCode AS CUSTOMER, Name as Customer Name , Add as Address 
FROM customer
```

Now, the export looks like the below.

```
Customer,Customer Name,Address
AA00,Hla Hla,Ms,Yangon
AA02,Kyaw,U,Taunggyi
```

So, I want to use a stored procedure that , case. There is Execute SQL task in Control Flow. But I don't know how to execute flat file by using that procedure.

Please kindly suggest

Comment: What's your current code?

Comment: I added OLEDB Source & Flat File Destination in Data Flow. my SQL stat is from OLEDB Source "SELECT  CustCode AS CUSTOMER, Name as Customer Name , Add as Address from customer"

Comment: thank you for your edit. By providing as much information as possible, users will understand your question better and find a solution easier.

Comment: When I edited your question, I left the reference to a stored procedure in the title, in case that had something to do with this that isn't immediately apparent. But there's no mention of a stored procedure anywhere in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Change the Exported Flat File Column Delimiter VS2012 SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356180/how-do-i-change-the-exported-flat-file-column-delimiter-vs2012-ssis)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the column delimiter property from the Flat File connection manager to `Tab`:

[image]

*Image reference: http://sqlknowledgebank.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssis-dynamic-flat-file-connection.html*

**Additional Information about Flat File connection manager**

- [Flat File Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Add and configure a Flat File connection manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-2-adding-and-configuring-a-flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: When I change column delimiter as Tab, csv file is show like that  

CustomerCustomer NameAddress
AA00Hla Hla                MsYangon
AA02Kyaw                  UTaunggyi


Actually I want to get the below format in csv file

Customer Customer Name    Address
AA00     Hla Hla,Ms       Yangon
AA02     Kyaw,U           Taunggyi